# Display a pdf in a form in ExtJS 3.4

Tags: pdf, extjs3

I would like to create a `form` with `fields` at top and a `pdf` in the middle with `ExtJS 3.4`.
Displaying a `pdf` is no problem, a `form` with `fields` is no problem but putting both together did not work yet.

Displaying a `pdf` works with a `panel`, a `form` with `fields` is a `Ext.form.FormPanel`.

How can I embed the `pdf` in the `form`?

**Here is what I tried:**

```
var pdfForm = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    id: 'pdfForm',
    width: 700,
    cloasable: false,
    waitMsgTarget: true,
    items: [{
        region: 'north',
        autoHeight: true,
        layout: 'column',
        border: false,
        defaults: {
            bodyStyle: 'padding:10px'
        },
        items: [{
            columnWidth: 0.5,
            layout: 'form',
            border: false,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Z',
                id: 'Z',
                name: 'Z',
                readOnly: true,
                anchor: '95%'
            }, {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'X',
                name: 'X',
                readOnly: true,
                anchor: '95%'
            }]
        }, {
            columnWidth: 0.5,
            layout: 'form',
            border: false,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Y',
                name: 'y',
                readOnly: true,
                anchor: '95%'
            }, {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'M',
                name: 'M',
                readOnly: true,
                anchor: '95%'
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        region: 'center',
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        id: 'tabs',
        plain: true,
        activeTab: 4,
        activeItem: 4,
        layoutOnTabChange: true,
        defaults: {
            bodyStyle: 'padding:0px'
        },
        deferredRender: false
    }, {
        region: 'south',
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'box',
            autoEl: {
                tag: 'iframe',
                id: 'samplePDF',
                name: 'samplePDF',
                style: 'height: 100%; width: 100%',
                src: 'http://' + serverIP + '/documents/18/bc1bca0a-d437-4505-aee4-9cbe63553a6d'
            }
        }]

    }]
});
```

The decisive code is in the last few lines. `"autoel"` does not match with the `Ext.form.FormPanel`. 
Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
The main step is to use an `Ext.Panel` instead of a `form`.

```
var formPanel = new Ext.Panel({
    frame: true,
    renderTo: 'formPanel',
    scrollable: 'true',
    title: '',
    id: 'mainPanel',
    autoHeight: true,
    autoWidth: true,
    layout: 'form',
    items: [{
        region: 'north',
        autoHeight: true,
        layout: 'column',
        border: false,
        defaults: {
            bodyStyle: 'padding:10px'
        },
        items: [{
            columnWidth: 0.5,
            layout: 'form',
            border: false,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: '1',
                id: '1',
                name: '1',
                readOnly: true,
                anchor: '95%'
            }]
        }, {
            columnWidth: 0.5,
            layout: 'form',
            border: false,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: '2',
                name: '2',
                readOnly: true,
                anchor: '95%'
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        region: 'center',
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        id: 'tabs',
        plain: true,
        activeTab: 4,
        activeItem: 4,
        layoutOnTabChange: true,
        defaults: {
            bodyStyle: 'padding:0px'
        },
        deferredRender: false
    }, {
        region: 'south',
        xtype: 'box',
        autoEl: {
            tag: 'embed',
            id: '3',
            name: '3',
            style: 'height: 100%; width: 100%',
            type: 'application/pdf',
            src: 'http://<ip>/<path>.pdf'
        }
    }]
});

var pdfDlg = new Ext.Window({
    id: 'pdfDialog',
    title: 'PDF',
    layout: 'fit',
    width: 1000,
    height: 700,
    minWidth: 1000,
    minHeight: 500,
    closeAction: 'hide',
    closable: true,
    resizable: false,
    plain: true,
    modal: true,
    items: 'mainPanel',
    constrainHeader: true
});
```